# When forecasting a time series using artificial intelligence, why aren't the errors diagnostic?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, residuals, diagnostic

Modern methods for predicting or forecasting time series have become widely used, such as neural network, fuzzy logic, ANFIS, etc. When we use these method for time series forecasting, errors are not used diagnostically (e.g. checking normality, independence, etc) unlikely the methodology in traditional methods such as ARIMA. Why is this?